# Simple modules over $KA_4$

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to find the simple $KA_4$-modules when $K$ has characteristic 2. I know that these are in bijection with the $KC_3 $ -modules. First of all, how do I find these and then how do I transfer that to $KA_4$?

Comment: Do you assume $K$ is algebraically closed?